# как к свойству объекта добавить объект ?

Tags: javascript

```
есть такой объект 
var parent={
       title:"1",
       model:"Category",
       alias:"catedory",
       depthMenu:{
            menu1:{
                title:"2",
                model:"Category",
                alias:"category"}
      }
```

мне к свойству depthMenu надо добавить ещё такой объект

```
menu2:{
    title:3,
    model:Category,
    alias:category}
```

что бы получилось так

```
var parent={
           title:"1",
           model:"Category",
           alias:"catedory",
           depthMenu:{
                menu1:{
                    title:"2",
                    model:"Category",
                    alias:"category"},
                 menu2:{
                    title:3,
                    model:Category,
                    alias:category}
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде бы всё просто, добавляете так же как и добавляли бы просто свойство:

```js
var parent={
 title:"1",
 model:"Category",
 alias:"catedory",
 depthMenu:{
  menu1:{
    title:"2",
    model:"Category",
    alias:"category"}
  } 
};

var menu2 = {
  title:3,
  model: 'Category',
  alias:'catedory'
};

parent.depthMenu.menu2 = menu2;

console.log(parent);
```

UPD: Если брать в пример код с комментария, то решение следующее:

```
if (parent) {
  if (typeof parent.depthMenu == "undefined") {
    parent.depthMenu = {};
  }
  parent.depthMenu[key] = addmenu; 
}
```

Замените строки где в цикле вы вставляли пункты, вы каждый раз перебивали `depthMenu`, в моем варианте если его нет, то создает при первом проходе цикла и потом уже добавляет в него данные.

Comment: да чуть в другом собственно вот здесь все видно https://codepen.io/sirgalas/pen/dWgPvx за формирование объекта отвечают строки с 76 по 96

Comment: @Sergalas так там же совсем другой код, чем вы показали, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое все получилось